# List of neearby searched types IOS xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps

So this piece of code gets nearest searchedTypes(atms and banks) for google and puts markers around the map.

```
private func fetchNearbyPlaces(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

    mapView.clear()

    dataProvider.fetchPlacesNearCoordinate(coordinate, radius:searchRadius, types: searchedTypes) { places in
        places.forEach {
            let marker = PlaceMarker(place: $0)
            marker.map = self.mapView

        }
    }
}
```

How do I get a table view with the list of these nearest searedTypes and get information on them to show on another viewcontroller where I can navigate from user location to that point. How the normal google maps works.

Answer (score 0):

With places acquired, you can pass data to a new controller that has table view and display data there.